# Capture updated rows in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I don't write T-SQL code too often so how do I capture updated row in a trigger?
If I create a trigger for `INSERT` I can ask for records from `inserted` as in

```
Create Trigger [dbo].[tr_test]
on table1
for INSERT
as

declare @id int
select @id = i.RecordId from inserted as I
...
```

How do I do that for UPDATE?

Comment: Your have a **fundamental flaw** in your trigger code: you assume the trigger is called **once per row** - this is **NOT** the case with SQL Server. If your `INSERT` or `UPDATE` affects multiple rows, the trigger will be called **once per statement**, and the pseudo tables `Inserted` and `Deleted` can contain multiple rows. So which of these rows are you selecting when doing `select @id1 = i.RecordId from inserted i;` ??? It's not defined - you get **one, arbitrary** row and all other are ignored.... you need to re-write your trigger to handle **multiple rows** in `Inserted` and `Deleted` !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way as with an insert trigger. In an update trigger, `inserted` contains the new values, and `deleted` contains the old.

Quoth the docs:

> The deleted table stores copies of the affected rows during DELETE and UPDATE statements. During the execution of a DELETE or UPDATE statement, rows are deleted from the trigger table and transferred to the deleted table. The deleted table and the trigger table ordinarily have no rows in common.
>
> The inserted table stores copies of the affected rows during INSERT and UPDATE statements. During an insert or update transaction, new rows are added to both the inserted table and the trigger table. The rows in the inserted table are copies of the new rows in the trigger table.
>
> An update transaction is similar to a delete operation followed by an insert operation; the old rows are copied to the deleted table first, and then the new rows are copied to the trigger table and to the inserted table.

Source: [DML Triggers, Use the inserted and deleted Tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms191300.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

There are are two trigger or magic tables  in sql server that is inserted or deleted table.

If you are creating trigger for **Insert**
- data comes in only inserted table in deleted table there is no records find

```
Create Trigger [dbo].[tr_test]
on table1
for INSERT
as
if exists (select 1 from inserted) and not exists(select 1 from deleted)
-- Action which would you want For Insert
```

If you are creating trigger for **Update**
- updated data comes in only inserted table and previous data comes in deleted table there is no records find

```
Create Trigger [dbo].[tr_test]
on table1
for UPDATE
as
if exists (select 1 from inserted) and  exists(select 1 from deleted)
-- Action which would you want when your target table has been update
```

If you are creating trigger for **Delete**
- Deleted data comes in Deleted table and in case of deleting data it not comes inserted table.

```
Create Trigger [dbo].[tr_test]
on table1
after  Delete
as
if exists (select 1 from deleted ) and not exists(select 1 from inserted)
-- Action which would you want when your target table has been delete
```